# Keeping eigenvalues of $A-BDC$ in the left half plane

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

Suppose $A$ is a given $n \times n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that  $Re(\lambda)\le 0$.  Also given are matrix $B$ as $n\times p$ and matrix $C$ as $p\times n$.  How can we control matrix $D$, which is $p \times p$, so that the eigenvalues of $W=A-BDC$ satisfy $Re(\lambda)<0$?